# angular js $scope is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't retrieve value of email in my controller. I get value 'undefined'.
My form:

```
<form role="form" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Email Address" formnovalidate>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" ng-click="submit()" value="Register" class="btn btn-info btn-block">
</form>
```

My controller:

```
app.controller('RegistrationController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.submit = function () {       
        alert($scope.user.email);
        alert(this.user.email);
    };
});
```

Comment: Wasn't your code minified before run?

Comment: Could you create [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/)?

Comment: move ng-click="submit()" to the <form> tag and change it to ng-submit="submit()", and the alert(this.user.email) line should be deleted, it doesn't make sense in this context.

Answer (score 2):

I assume, it's happening because angular validates your input, and unless you provide valid email - model will be `undefined`

[See my plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/HmQV5Ou3sFjaOv6o6ADB?p=preview)

[input[email] directive documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D)

Comment: I agree. Not sure what input he/she's using that it's coming up undefined but if it doesn't look like an email address it will be undefined.